# Javascript in html not working, not even alert

Tags: javascript, html

I added the alert to test if the script was working at all, once i deleted the function it did, but once I add the function the html doesn't even show the alert. I tried loading the code in a different file and calling it in the head, the body, for some reason the code won't even load much less can i get the button at the end to work.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Astronomy Quiz </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <script>
                alert("Quiz");
                function quiz() {
                    var grade = 0;
                    var get = document.getElementById("quiz");
                    if (get.q1[1].checked) {
                        grade += 1;
                    } else if (!get.q1[0].checked) {
                        alert("Please answer the first question.");
                        return;
                    }

                    if (get.q2[0].checked) {
                        grade += 1;
                    } else if (!get.q2[1].checked) {
                        alert("Please answer the second question.");
                        return;
                    }
                    var check = 0;
                    var gradeCheck = 0;
                    if (get.q3[1].checked) {
                        check += 1;
                        gradeCheck += 1;
                    }
                    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                        if (get.q3[i].checked && i != 1) {
                            check += 1;
                            gradeCheck = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    if (check == 0) {
                        alert("Please answer the third question.");
                        return;
                    }
                    grade += gradeCheck;
                    check = 0;
                    gradeCheck = 0;
                    if (get.q4[3].checked) {
                        check += 1;
                        gradeCheck += 1;
                    }
                    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                        if (get.q4[i].checked && i != 3) {
                            check += 1;
                            gradeCheck = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    if (check == 0) {
                        alert("Please answer the fourth question.");
                        return;
                    }
                    grade += gradeCheck;
                    if (get.q5.value.match(/^galaxy$/i)) {
                        grade += 1;
                    }
                    if (get.q5.value == "") {
                        alert("PLease answer the fifth question.");
                        return;
                    }
                    if (get.q6.value.match(/^age$/i)) {
                        grade += 1;
                    }
                    if (get.q6.value == "") {
                        alert("PLease answer the sixth question.");
                        return;
                    }
                    alert("Your grade is " + grade + " / 6.");
                }
            </script>
            <center>
                <h1> Astronomy Quiz </h1>
            </center>
            <h3> True / False </h3>
            <form id = "quiz">
                <label><b>1)</b> According to Kepler the orbit of the earth is a circle with
                    the sun at the center.
                    <input type = "radio" name = "q1" value = "True" />
                    True
                    <input type = "radio" name = "q1" value = "False" />
                    False</label>
                <br>
                <br>

                <label><b>2)</b> Ancient astronomers did consider the heliocentric model of
                    the solar system but rejected it because they could not detect parallax.
                    <input type = "radio" name = "q2" value = "True" />
                    True
                    <input type = "radio" name = "q2" value = "True" />
                    False</label>
                <br>

                <h3> Multiple Choice </h3>
                <b>3)</b> The total amount of energy that a star emits is directly related
                to its
                <br>
                <input type = "checkbox" name = "q3" value = "a" />
                a) surface gravity and magnetic field
                <br>
                <input type = "checkbox" name = "q3" value = "b" />
                b) radius and temperature
                <br>
                <input type = "checkbox" name = "q3" value = "c" />
                c) pressure and volume
                <br>
                <input type = "checkbox" name = "q3" value = "d" />
                d) location and velocity
                <br>
                <br>

                <b>4)</b> Stars that live the longest have
                <br>
                <input type = "checkbox" name = "q4" value = "a" />
                a) high mass
                <br>
                <input type = "checkbox" name = "q4" value = "b" />
                b) high temperature
                <br>
                <input type = "checkbox" name = "q4" value = "c" />
                c) lots of hydrogen
                <br>
                <input type = "checkbox" name = "q4" value = "d" />
                d) small mass
                <br>

                <h3> Fill in the Blank </h3>
                <label><b>5)</b> A collection of a hundred billion stars, gas, and dust is
                    called a
                    <input type = "text" name = "q5" value = "" size = "15" />
                    .</label>
                <br>
                <br>

                <label><b>6)</b> The inverse of the Hubble's constant is a measure of the
                    <input type = "text" name = "q6" value = "" size = "15" />
                    of the universe.</label>
                <br>
                <br />
                <input type = "button" value = "Grade" onclick = "quiz()" />
                <input type = "reset" name = "Clear" value = "Clear" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fixed and wellformatted your script

Comment: Install firebug or something similar and debug your script.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by a missing bracket

Comment: It's running fine now.

Comment: I would recommend learning about the debugging tools included in modern browsers, see [firebug (For FireFox)](http://getfirebug.com/), [chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) and [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699336(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/fDDCW/

**JS:-**

```
alert("Quiz");

function quiz() {
    var grade = 0;
    var get = document.getElementById("quiz");
    if (get.q1[1].checked) {
        grade += 1;
    } else if (!get.q1[0].checked) {
        alert("Please answer the first question.");
        return;
    }

    if (get.q2[0].checked) {
        grade += 1;
    } else if (!get.q2[1].checked) {
        alert("Please answer the second question.");
        return;
    }
    var check = 0;
    var gradeCheck = 0;
    if (get.q3[1].checked) {
        check += 1;
        gradeCheck += 1;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (get.q3[i].checked && i != 1) {
            check += 1;
            gradeCheck = 0;
        }
    }
    if (check == 0) {
        alert("Please answer the third question.");
        return;
    }
    grade += gradeCheck;
    check = 0;
    gradeCheck = 0;
    if (get.q4[3].checked) {
        check += 1;
        gradeCheck += 1;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (get.q4[i].checked && i != 3) {
            check += 1;
            gradeCheck = 0;
        }
    }
    if (check == 0) {
        alert("Please answer the fourth question.");
        return;
    }
    grade += gradeCheck;
    if (get.q5.value.match(/^galaxy$/i)) {
        grade += 1;
    }
    if (get.q5.value == "") {
        alert("PLease answer the fifth question.");
        return;
    }
    if (get.q6.value.match(/^age$/i)) {
        grade += 1;
    }
    if (get.q6.value == "") {
        alert("PLease answer the sixth question.");
        return;
    }
    alert("Your grade is " + grade + " / 6.");
    }
```

Comment: Appreciate the quick response

Answer (score 1):

on line 88:

```
if(get.q6.value.match(/^age$/i))
```

you missed `)` in your javascript...

Comment: if(get.q6.value.match(/^age$/i))

Comment: in your javascript, find 'if(get.q6.value.match(/^age$/i)' and replace it to 'if(get.q6.value.match(/^age$/i))'

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a `)` here:

`if(get.q6.value.match(/^age$/i)`

Change this to:

`if(get.q6.value.match(/^age$/i))`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (get.q6.value.match(/^age$/i) {
```

This like is missing a closing )

Try this:

```
if (get.q6.value.match(/^age$/i)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

To **find what's wrong** with your JavaScript code **use `try-catch`** as follows-

```
<script>
     try
     {
       /*some JS code*/
     }
     catch(foo)//Use any variable in place of foo
     {
       alert(foo);
     }
</script>
```

This will definitely not correct the error but may help you much to find **what the error is**. Though this is not an answer but you may follow this approach globally *anywhere anytime*.

Comment: Or use a one of the javascript debugging tools that are included in **every** modern browser, see [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), [chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) and [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699336(v=vs.85).aspx)